# Angular set position using NgStyle doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular8

I have problem with setting position using NgStyle for the following code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let handlePosition of handlePositions; let i = index;">
      <div [ngStyle]="{'transform': 'translate(' + value + 'px, 0px)'}" class="handle-slider__handle"
        [ngDraggable]="fc.enabled"
        [lockAxis]="'y'"
        [bounds]="handleSlider"
        [inBounds]="inBounds"
        [position]="{ x: handlePosition, y: 0 }"
        (endOffset)="onHandleChange($event, i)"></div>
    </ng-container>
```

it seems like ngStyle doesnt apply changes for the element. Could some1 point me how to fix this?

@EDIT
I have done it like that, but there has to be a way of doing it in angular.

```
setHandleMaxPosition() {
    const tempValues = this.fc.value;
    tempValues[1] = this.values[this.indexOfNearestMax];
    this.fc.setValue(tempValues);
    this.handlePositions[1] = this.valuePositions[this.indexOfNearestMax];

    var a = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('handle-slider__handle') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>)
    a[1].style.transform = "translate(" + this.valuePositions[this.indexOfNearestMin] + "px, 0px)";
  }
```

Comment: The doc says the unit must be present

Comment: it is not present unfortunatelly

Comment: What is the value of the `value` ? :D This should work with ngStyle if it is contains a number value

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `value` variable is contains a number value ?

Beacuse the `[ngStyle]="{'transform': 'translate(' + value + 'px, 0px)'}"` looks good to me.

Comment: public value: numeric = 100;

as a default, but whenever I change this value style isnt applied...

Comment: Can you provide an example or something ? 

I had try out more variation and all of them worked. U can check it out here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngstyle-position-62551883